# Is there a way to disable javascript for just a part of my HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, jqbootstrapvalidation

I'm using a bootstrap template which use "jqBootstrapValidation.js" (http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation) to validate it's forms. I edit template and add a form to it, but my submit button doesn't work!when I comment the script which inculde "jqBootstrapValidation.js", my submit button get to work! I don't want to edit the Javascript file. Is there a way to disable it for **just my form**?

this is my form:

```
<form name="register" id="regForm" name="input" action="pay.php" method="post">
        <div class="row control-group">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                     <label> email</label>
                     <input type="email" class="form-control" 
                         id="email" required>
                     <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
             </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row control-group">
              <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                     <label>Telephone</label>
                     <input type="tel" class="form-control"  id="phone" required>
                     <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
        </div>

        <div id="success"></div>

        <div class="row" align="left">
               <div class="form-group col-xs-12">               
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
                      register
                    </button>
               </div>
         </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: You cannot. unless you find out which selector the javascript file uses and use another class or id for your form.

Comment: you really need to share your code - we've no idea how functions are wired to the form. javascript is pretty flexible almost certainly there will be a way even if very clunky

Comment: @hamed - add your form tag and entry point - its unlikely to have more than one entry point to the js?

Comment: You could put the form in an iframe. Though this is as messy as every other work-around.

Comment: @jenson-button-event I used this bootstrap theme: [link]http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/, I edit lots of code, but no change in jqBootstrapValidation.js file.

Comment: @jenson-button-event when I create a new form, this js file prevent "submit" btn to work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the special form is on a single page, you can remove that big script link.
Alternatively, you can use jQuery to load the JS file dynamically.

```
if(!$("#myformid")){
    $.getScript("ajax/test.js");
}
```

Comment: I understand that there is no way to disable Java-Script for a form,So your solution is better for me :), thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could override the function

Assuming its a global function e.g.

```
function handleForm () {
  //existing code
}
```

override:

```
var originalFunction = window.handleForm; //store for future use
window.handleForm = function() {
  //psuedo code
  if(form is the one with this id/class/whatever call) newFunction();
  else originalFunction();
}
```

Comment: also I didn't want to do that, but this is a good solution

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you supply at least some of the script.

I'd change the class name or id of the form (or element that contains the form) or the class names of the input elements. It Depends on what DOM hook the script acts upon.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick up the form and unbind all events on it. Recommend use jQuery to resolve it.

Comment: @Hamed Gh advise you can push your code and explain what you do for now.

Comment: I try to add my js file, but there is limitation on character. it is over 30000 character!